# Facebook comment Box and canvas height

Tags: facebook, comments

I'm trying to add a comment box to my app. Now the problem is that facebook max canvas height is 800px. Now, if someone adds a few comments you can't see it because it's going over the 800px. 
I've tried to use setSize.. but I don't know what is the comment height that the user entered..

I just want the page height to change according to the current comment box height.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the canvas height to Fluid in the app's advanced settings.
If you set it to Settable(height: 800px), you can still use [FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/) to make it resize automatically.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know this option ...Is it new ? It does not documented under facebook developers docs.